# Javascript em arquivo funcionando de forma intermitente

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Estou utilizando javascript para realizar requisições ajax toda vez que é selecionado um item numa combo. Para isso a tag Select executa o evento Onchange.

Porém estou tendo problemas na chamada da função js que está funcionando de forma intermitente. Tem vezes que o valor é alterado e a função não é executada.

Esse é o trecho do JS que deve ser executado toda vez que o select for alterado:

```html
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.tbl select.detalhes').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            var id = $(this).val();
            AjaxCall(urlPrefix + 'Detalhe.aspx/Ficha', '{ id: ' + id + ' }', function (data) {
                carregarFicha(data);
            });
            $(this).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
        }
    });
```

Código cshtml onde insiro o html no **@section Head**:

```html
@model IList<Round>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/SiteLayout.cshtml";
}
@section Head
{
 <script src="@Url.NonCached("~/Scripts/Index.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}

@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    <h2>Rodada</h2>    
    var textoRodadas = @Model.Count > 0 ? "Rodadas encontradas" : "Rodada encontrada";         
    <span class="total-registros"> <strong>@Model.Count</strong> @textoRodadas</span>    
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tbl" id="table-round">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th scope="col" class="ord">Rodada</th>
    <th scope="col" class="ord">Data Inicial</th>
    <th scope="col" class="ord">Data Final</th>
    <th scope="col" width="150" class="ord tits-th col-escura ">Regras</th>    
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
  
   var item = Model[i];
            var classe = "class=\"" + item.Tipo.ToString();
            if (item.Protegido == SimNao.Sim)
            {
                classe += " protegido ";
            }
            classe += i % 2 == 0 ? "\"" : " odd\"";

            var permitirCriarRegraComLances = !(item.Tipo == App.AdjudicacaoInicial);
                
            <tr @Html.Raw(classe) >
    <td class="tbl-nomeTipo-round") ">
     @Html.Hidden("id", item.Id)
     <span class="click-round tbl-nome-round">@item.Nome</span>
    </td>
    <td class="click-round tbl-data-round">
     @item.DataInicio.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    </td>
    <td class="click-round tbl-data-round">
     @item.DataFim.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    </td>
    <td class="col-escura">
      <div  class="grid-12-12 form">
      @{
      var regras = item.Regras.OrderBy(t => t.Nome).ToArray();
      }
      <span class="txt-maior ">@regras.Length</span>
      @if (regras.Length > 0)
      {
     <select class="form-txt regras" id="reg1" onchange="mudou(this)">
      <option value="" >Selecione</option>
       @foreach (var reg in regras)
       {
       <option value="@reg.Id">@reg.Nome</option>   
       }
     </select>
      }
     
      </div>     
    </td>
   </tr>            
        }
  </tbody>
 </table>
}
else
{
 <span>Sem resultados</span>
}
```

**UPDATE**

*Não está mais funcionando corretamente nem embutindo o JS diretamente no cshtml ao invés de referenciar o arquivo.*

**UPDATE 2**

Esqueci de mencionar que a aplicação só é homologada para o Firefox e que o código funcionava corretamente até a empresa atualizar alguns clientes com a versão 60.7.0. Essa versão específica é que deve estar causando o problema. 
Já sugeri a atualização, mas a empresa tem muitas burocracias e a infra  controla as atualizações.

Comment: Só funciona 1 vez?

Comment: Funciona de forma intermitente, selecionando algumas opções aleatórias.

Comment: Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode estar ocasionando o problema ou alguma alguma implementação melhor para essa situação?